# Calling stored procedures through ODBC without declaring parameter placeholders

Tags: c#, mysql, string, odbc, procedure

I'm currently trying to abstract the calling of stored procedures through `ODBC` by making a function that requires a procedure name as string and a set of keys and values as a dictionary. Because of this, I have to build up a string for the `ODBC Command` which is.. yeah, silly.

```
CALL myProcedure(?, ?, ?, ?)
```

and then with the ODBC command object:

```
odbcCommand.Parameters.AddWithValue("key", "param");
```

Now for adding the parameters I can easily do a `foreach`. Or even LINQ-style with `Select`. But I also have to create the `CALL`-string with the question marks where I have to be careful that something like this never happens:

```
CALL myProcedure(?, ?, ?, )
```

So I have to loop one time through the dictionary for adding the parameters and a second time for joining the keys and values to a string (`String.Join`) or I loop through everything with a `FOR`-loop and have to check if the current `KeyValuePair` is the last one just to prevent accidentally commata at the end of the string.

Isn't there a way where I just can declare "`CALL myProcedure`" or even something like

```
odbcCommand.CommandType = CommandTypes.StoredProcedure;
odbcCommand.ProcedureName = "myProcedure";
[LOOP]
     - add Params damn comfortable
[/LOOP]
```

I hope there is.. it would help me reduce an extra step required because of nonesense!

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

After adding the parameters, use this:

```
int paramCount = odbcCommand.Parameters.Count();
string[] placeholders = Enumerable.Repeat("?", paramCount).ToArray();
string callParams = String.Join(", ", placeholders);
```

Then you no longer have to be careful to avoid the trailing comma referred to in the CALL-string.
(I realize this doesn't fully answer your question of eliminating the placeholders.)